# Partial derivatives at critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

If $f(x,y)$ is a continuous and differentiable function then $f_x=f_y=0$  at local maximum, minimim and saddle points.How to prove this?

Comment: What do you mean "without using the tangent plane"? Just talking about $f_x$ and $f_y$ at all could be considered "using the tangent plane". So it not at all clear what you are after.

Comment: I am asking for some Argument to justify this theorem

Comment: I have edited that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove

- If $f(x,y)$ is differentiable on an open set containing $(x_0,y_0)$ and $f$ has a local extremum at $(x_0,y_0)$, then $(x_0,y_0)$ is a critical point of $f$.

Define $B_r(x,y)$ as the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $(x,y)$. Suppose $f(x,y)$ is differentiable on an open set containing $(x_0,y_0)$ and $f$ has a local extremum at $(x_0,y_0)$. Let $r>0$ so that $f$ is differentiable $B_r(x_0,y_0)$. Let $g$ be a function of one variable defined by $g(x)=f(x,y_0)$ with $x$ satisfying $(x,y_0)\in B_r(x_0,y_0)$, i.e., $x\in(x_0-r,x_0+r)$.

Now, $g(x)$ is differentiable and $g$ attains its extreme value at $x=x_0$, since $f_x(x,y_0)=g'(x)$. Therefore, $g'(x_0)=0$. Hence, $f_x(x_0,y_0)=0$. A similar argument can be used to show that $f_y(x_0,y_0)=0$.

Comment: That works for extrema. Saddle points are a bit more complicated because neither cardinal direction need have an extrema at the point. But the definition of "saddle point" requires some direction has a minimum and some other direction has a maximum. And you can use this and a little (very little) linear algebra to show that every direction at the saddle point has derivative $0$.

Comment: Why  g(x) should attain its extreme value at $x=x_0$?

Comment: Let's assume were talking about its a maximum. Suppose $g$ attains its maximum value at some other point $x_1\in(x_0-r,x_0+r)$. Then $f(x_1,y_0)=g(x_1)>g(x_0)=f(x_0,y_0)$. But then $(x_0,y_0)$ is not a local max of $f$.